# Bitmap causes custom list view to scroll laggy

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap, baseadapter

I am using view holder/recycling view correctly. The list view itself is set to `match_parent` My custom list view is smooth until i give the image a value.

```
Bitmap flagPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.mContext.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.afganistanicon);
                holder.feedProfilePic.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(flagPic, 100, 90, false));
```

Maybe the problem is with my list row item layout activity?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/feedThumbnailId"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedProfilePic"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_always_landscape_portrait"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/feedUsernameId"
android:text="username"
android:textColor="#282727"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/feedThumbnailId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feedTextId"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="#282727"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:text="status"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feedDownVoteButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feedDate"
    android:text="x hours ago"
    android:textColor="#282727"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/feedCommentButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feedTextId"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feedRepliesNumId"
    android:text="y replies"
    android:textColor="#282727"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/feedCommentButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feedNumofLikes"
    android:text="x likes"
    android:textColor="#282727"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/feedUpVoteButton"
    android:text="Up"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/feedNumofLikes"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:focusable="false" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/feedDownVoteButton"
    android:text="DW"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feedUpVoteButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/feedNumofLikes"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: Try using Glide Library.

Comment: I ended up using a class which `extends Imageview` and referencing it in my XML layout. It fixed 80% of the lag.